# Cache does not work in Laravel queues

Tags: php, laravel, caching, queue

I have a cron job script and it fetches weather for different places from third party API. This script takes places from database and in foreach loop I dispatch a job for every place:

```
foreach($places as $place) {
    $job = new WeatherCheck($place);
    dispatch($job)
}
```

If there places with the same coordinates, it is supposed, that weather is fetched from cache, but cache does not work, it is taken from API directly. But when I run this task next time, weather is taken from cache.

To summarize, weather is not taken from cache only in the same task, but in the next task ccache works fine.

Comment: Isn't that how caching is supposed to work? Am I missing something?

Comment: @apokryfos is correct. If you use caching, this is so that you don't have to hit the API repeatedly. So you cache the result, and next time you need the data, you get the data from the cache rather than hitting the API. Now, with your caching layer, you will need to decide how / when to invalidate the cache (when the cache expires). e.g. maybe it is the next day or hour, so you need to specify how long the cache is valid for. It would be good to see your code inside `WeatherCheck` - so that we can see how you have implemented your caching if it is doing something you dont expect.

Comment: @apokryfos I think you don't understand what I wanna say. I do cache weather results and cache always works fine. But if I run Laravel Queues and run jobs that take weather from API, results always come from API even for the same place even if thay were cached.

Comment: @StasCoder you shouldn't abandon your question once you've asked it. Barely anyone will be able to find it now. Also you have not supplied any information on how you are utilizing the cache, most likely you're using a different cache key when running from the queue.

Comment: @apokryfos I use different keys, because cache works fine when I run my jobs at different time